# Connecting Mobilinkd TNC2 to Mac for Xastir

Tags: aprs, tnc

I am not sure what to put in the TNC Port window on Xastir if I'm using a Mobilinkd TNC2.  Xastir has directions for just this however, it is for Ubuntu Linux. https://xastir.org/index.php/HowTo:BluetoothTNC  I'm on Mac OSX 10.15.5 and rfcomm doesn't exist.

I think I need to bind the bluetooth device/port to another port to keep it open.  I may be making stuff up though.

I have tried entering the ports from /dev/* that are related to the device (ie. tty.MobilinkdTNC2-DevB) but it still fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After pairing to the TNC, use the "cu.***" port as the address in Xastir.

For me it was: `/dev/cu.MobilinkdTNC2-DevB`. Set the baud to 9600 and click done.

My connection failed after about 15 minutes.  I unpaired, repaired, and then the connection stayed up.

Comment: Good work!  Sorry nobody else participated in this one, but we appreciate the question and the answer!  I'll look forward to more from you.